# Can you find a 2-form not written as the wedge of two 1-forms?

Tags: exterior-algebra

I was under the impression that all 2-forms are the wedge $(\wedge)$ of two 1-forms. Is it possible to have a 2-form that you can't write as $A\wedge B$ with $A,B$  1-forms?

Comment: The question in your title is the opposite of the question in the body of your thread.  Mariano is responding to the latter.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible. (And you should find an example yourself: I will not deprive you of the joy of finding it :) )

Comment: Would dA^dB+dC^dD (in R^4) be an example? It's a two form but it can't be written as A^B

Comment: @JimJones: your example works, but you should not be satisfied until you have a proof of this.  Just because you try to write it as the wedge of two one-forms and fail is of course not enough...

Comment: @Mariano, awesome answer

Comment: I still just don't understand

Comment: @JimJones. I assume that $A,B,C,D$ in your first formula are functions... (Maybe I could add to Mariano's answer: simply look at the definition of 2-forms and remember something about linear independence.)

Comment: A,B,C,D are suppose to be 1-forms... is that wrong?

Comment: @JimJones: you don't have to understand: you have to compute. Find the general form of a $2$-form which is a wedge product of two $1$-forms, and next show that not all $2$-forms are of that form.

Comment: The definition I was given in class is "a k-form is a function taking p to a k-linear alternating map on TR^n. These look like linear combinations of dx^1^dx^2^..." I was under the impression that the definition of a 2-form is the wedge of two one forms... that's why I'm lost

Comment: If you think a 2-form is *that* then what you need is to read up a bit on what forms are :)

Comment: @JimJones. If $A,B,C,D$ are 1-forms, then $dA, dB, dC, dD$ are 2-forms. Then $dA\wedge dB$ and $dC\wedge dD$ are 4-forms.

Comment: @JimJones. As for your "look like linear combinations": that's ok. And you are making linear combinations of *which* kind of vectors? Can you find a linear combination of $dx\wedge dy, dy\wedge dz, dz \wedge dx$ equal to zero -different from the trivial one?